MongoDB - Overwrite the whole array field instead of its item
I have this schema:{ key: [] }. I want to convert it to { key: { foo: number } }.
This is the query I came up with:
db.collection.update({}, [
  {
    "$set": {
      key: { foo: 43 }
    }
  }
], { multi: true })

However, it updates the individual array item instead of the array as a whole. I.e. the document:
{ key: [1, 2] }
becomes :
{ key: [ { foo: 43 }, { foo: 43 } ] }
instead of:
{ key: { foo: 43 } }.
I just want to get rid of the original array completely. I can just remove the field, then write the update. But is there a way to do it in one fell swoop?
Update: I have to use the pipeline, there're other stuff going on.

What about the 2 in [1, 2] ? You don't want it in the result { a: { foo: 1 } } ?

@aneroid I just want to get rid of the original array completely. I don't use the original value.

In that case, don't use the pipeline syntax for update. So you only need to remove the [...] surrounding $set:  db.collection.update({}, { "$set": { key: { foo: 43 } } }, { multi: true }) playground

Unfortunately, I have to use the pipeline.

If you keen to use aggregation pipeline, you should remove the a field with $unset, then $set. Demo

Use $literal
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "key": {
        "$literal": {
          "foo": 43
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Oh this is much nicer than mine

This is just awesome! Thanks!

As per this comment:

I just want to get rid of the original array completely. I don't use the original value.

In that case, don't use the pipeline syntax for update. So you only need to remove the [...] surrounding $set:
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    key: { foo: 43 }
  }
},
{ multi: true })

And if you do need an update pipeline for some other steps, then unset key before setting a new value:
db.collection.update({},
[
  { $unset: "key" },
  {
    $set: {
      key: { foo: 43 }
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true }
)

Mongo Playground
